# Is there an easy way to create a patch on one branch to apply to another branch if both branches share a common ancestor?

Tags: git, version, diff, commit, patch

I'll be referencing the graphic I made:

[image: Repo commit structure]

My question is: how do I generate patch Z to get from commit B to D?

I want only the functionality I added in Patch X (to get from commit A to C), but because commits A and B have diverged enough, that patch doesn't apply cleanly and leaves a lot of rejected hunks.

If I can create patch X and patch Y, is there a way to use patch Y as a "guide" for the patch program to know how to get from B to A, but don't apply patch Y and then apply patch X?

Comment: Is there an easy way? No. That's why instead of fixing the bug at point `A` is not the best idea; see [Raymond Chen's series](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20180323-01/?p=98325) on this.

Comment: @torek Yeah I agree, unfortunately, the branches for A and B have to remain a permanent fork in this repo (also not my favorite but it's not my repo to change) to support slightly different hardware versions (this is embedded firmware). I will be reading the Raymond Chen stuff because I'm trying to improve my git knowledge.

Comment: I would suggest you first patch the system that has diverged the least from the common ancestor. Then perhaps you can cherry-pick the commits and merge those to the other branch.  You might find some conflicts in this merge but they should be easily identifiable and straight-forward to resolve.